# How is Armament Haki obtained or learned?

Tags: one-piece

Armament Haki is being used by a number of users, namely Luffy, Sabo, Garp, Chinjao, etc.

So, has there been any explanation given about the process or training involved in obtaining this Haki ?

Comment: No, as far as I remember, there hasn't been any explanation how to train Haki.

Comment: The closest we came to knowing this was when Rayleigh was teaching Luffy on Rusukaina Island. He makes a very abstract statement about the need to train to develop one's Haki. However, we do not actually see Luffy's training, so we don't know as of now. This question is unanswerable as of now, but if a future flashback shows us Luffy's training, it would be answerable.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question based on this meta post: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/307/99 There is a realistic chance of Luffy's training at Rusukaina being shown in more detail in a future flashback, so this question would become answerable then.

Comment: @MaskedMan thankx mate. I was just curious about it and yeah I will be waiting for that future flashback

Comment: Oh well, I thought I should open a meta post (after posting in chat) to ask for reopen votes http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2368/99, and by the time I finished that, there are 4 votes already. I suppose I just did a [There Is No Kill Like Overkill](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThereIsNoKillLikeOverkill)? ... "So, Ohnoki, what will you do about the second one?" ;-)

Comment: @MaskedMan yeah saw the meta post and thanks for making effort

Comment: @exexzian It is one of those unwritten "community obligations" of a Trusted User. :-)

Comment: I would like to say that, as we have seen so far in the OP universe there was never a proper explanation from manga (because this is where we see what is really happening) for any skill from Luffy. We all remember that in the CP9 arc. Luffy show us 2 techniques that they were never mentioned or even properly introduced before. So, I don't think that we will have a chance to see any explanation. Also we can all see that Oda has a lot in his mind to show us, so I don't see he will have the proper time to explain. Maybe in a SBS he will tell us.

Comment: Well, althoug many don't like to take non-canon as reference: You can see how Luffys developed some of his techniques: karakuri castle, when Luffy is fighting the giant robot, you can see him using Gear 2 by accident, some of his development of his haki can be seen while fighting Burndi World.

Comment: Yeah but it's not like they gave us how he obtained or how he trained to do gear 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an introduction I will quote [the wiki page on Haki](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki):

> Haki is a mysterious power that is found in every living being in the world. It is not that different from the normal senses. However, most people do not notice it or fail to awaken it. Broadly, there are two types of Haki common to everyone, given the proper training

As mentioned here, everybody has the ability to learn Haki, given the proper training. We have seen lots of examples of people who had obtained Haki through training, like the girls from the [Kuja tribe](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kuja), Luffy during his training with Rayleigh, Cobi during his training with Garp, etc. Almost every person we have seen, that uses Haki has gone through some kind of training from a *Haki expert*. The problem is that **none of these training sessions have been shown** as of writing.

**Training is not the only way to obtain Haki though**. As mentioned in the introduction, Haki is not different from your normal senses and that means that you can also obtain Haki subconsciously. We have seen a handful of cases, where people had obtained Haki on their own, without any training whatsoever. Examples of this are Ace and Luffy obtaining Conqueror's Haki, Cobi and Usopp obtaining Observation Haki or Sai obtaining Armament Haki. So it does not mean you have to take training per se to obtain Haki, but it is well advised to take training to fully control your power. Ace for example was shown to have Conqueror's Haki, but it did not look like he ever learned how to control it properly.

Comment: You really think they will show haki training? I reckon some people would probably spend years after that trying to get it right :)

Comment: But where did we see those instances of haki without training? I don't remember Ussop or Ace

Comment: @TGamer another example is child Doflamingo's Emperors Haki being awakened. This happened due to his internal revelation rather than any training.

Comment: @JesseBarnett Yes but Ussop? Even Ace can be expected but Ussop is like the last character in the whole series who would actually awaken it

Comment: @TGamer clearly you have not read far enough. One working example is enough for proof in this answer, if you want to find out about Ussop then I suggest asking a new question yourself

Answer (score 1):

I think to obtain certain haki, you have to do special training or learn some kind of technique, for armament haki you would have to boost your strength and fighting spirit to concentrate enough power to learn armament haki. For observation haki, i think you would have to learn to concentrate on listening, hearing, seeing and smelling. Or(For people who want to learn it the easy way)you could meditate and begin to be more at peace, so you would be able to not only see, but also hear your surrounding better, so it's harder for your opponent to hit you. To learn conquerers' haki...

I don't know, that's really never been cleared before. Well hope this info helps those who want to learn haki.

Comment: if you have no reference for what you say or if what you say is just speculation and guesses, please consider leaving a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be at a certain level of skill before you can learn haki. All the characters have shown usage of haki before they went into special training to get better at it. If you picked the weakest person off the street you would first train them in combat for at least one to two years before they start to show signs of being able to use haki. Ussop is a good example because he was very weak and grew to some extent from battling with the straw hats. Even then he wouldn’t have been able to get training for haki. It was only after two more years of training and a stressful situation did he finally use observation haki to save Luffy from Sugar.